# Transformation Error

Tags: c++, opengl

I was using 'thebennybox' and his "Intro to Modern OpenGl Tutorial" before   getting stuck on video #5 where he begins to apply matrices to manipulate the positions of his vertices, however i had made it to the end of the video and applied all of the changes he had, yet my shader does not seem to apply the transformations his tutorial shows, my triangle does not move at all. I would like to know what i have missed or where I went wrong so i can get a better understanding of matrices.

I did not include any of the preprocessor directives but did not receive any errors while building the program.

---

Here is my Transform.h

```
using namespace std;

class Transform
{
public:

Transform(const glm::vec3& pos = glm::vec3(), const glm::vec3& rot = glm::vec3(), const glm::vec3& scale = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)) :
m_pos(pos),
m_rot(rot),
m_scale(scale) {}

inline glm::mat4 GetModel() const
{
    glm::mat4 posMatrix = glm::translate(m_pos);
    glm::mat4 rotXMatrix = glm::rotate(m_rot.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
    glm::mat4 rotYMatrix = glm::rotate(m_rot.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    glm::mat4 rotZMatrix = glm::rotate(m_rot.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::scale(m_scale);

    glm::mat4 rotMatrix = rotZMatrix * rotYMatrix * rotXMatrix;

    return  scaleMatrix * rotMatrix * posMatrix;

}

inline glm::vec3& GetPos() { return m_pos; }
inline glm::vec3& GetRot() { return m_rot; }
inline glm::vec3& GetScale() { return m_scale; }

inline void SetPos(glm::vec3& pos) { m_pos = pos; }
inline void SetRot(glm::vec3& rot) { m_rot = rot; }
inline void SetScale(glm::vec3& scale) { m_scale = scale; }

private:

glm::vec3 m_pos;
glm::vec3 m_rot;
glm::vec3 m_scale;
```

};

---

Here is my shader.h

```
using namespace std;

class Shader
{
public:
Shader(const string& fileName);

void Bind();
void Update(const Transform& transform);

virtual ~Shader();

private:
static const unsigned int NUM_SHADERS = 2;

void checkShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const string& errorMessage);

GLuint createShader(const string& fileName, unsigned int type);
string loaderShader(const string& text);

enum
{
    TRANSFORM_U,

    NUM_UNIFORMS

};

GLuint m_program;
GLuint m_shaders[NUM_SHADERS];
GLuint m_uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];
};
```

---

Here is my shader.cpp

```
using namespace std;

static GLuint createShader(const std::string& text, unsigned int type);
void checkShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const     std::string& errorMessage);
string loadShader(const string& fileName);

Shader::Shader(const string& fileName)
{
m_program = glCreateProgram();

m_shaders[0] = createShader(loaderShader(fileName + ".vs"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
m_shaders[1] = createShader(loaderShader(fileName + ".fs"), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
{
    cout << i << endl;
    glAttachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);

}

glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 0, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 1, "texCoord");


glLinkProgram(m_program);
checkShaderError(m_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, true, "Error: Linking Program!");

glValidateProgram(m_program);
checkShaderError(m_program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, true, "Error: Shader Invalid!");

m_uniforms[TRANSFORM_U] = glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "transform");


}

Shader::~Shader()
{
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
{
    glDetachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);
    glDeleteShader(m_shaders[i]);

}
glDeleteProgram(m_program);

}
void Shader::Bind()
{

glUseProgram(m_program);

}
void Shader::Update(const Transform& transform)
{
glm::mat4 model = transform.GetModel();
glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniforms[TRANSFORM_U], 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);

//to see the changes being applied to the matrix 
cout << model[0][0] << ", " << model[0][1] << ", " 
     << model[0][2] << ", " <<          model[0][3] << endl
     << model[1][0] << ", " << model[1][1] << ", "
     << model[1][2] << ", " << model[1][3] << endl
     << model[2][0] << ", " << model[2][1] << ", " 
     << model[2][2] << ", " << model[2][3] << endl
     << model[3][0] << ", " << model[3][1] << ", " 
     << model[3][2] << ", " << model[3][3] << endl;


 }
 string Shader::loaderShader(const string& fileName)
 {
ifstream input_stream;
string output, line;

input_stream.open((fileName).c_str());

if (input_stream.is_open())
{

    while (input_stream.good())
    {
        getline(input_stream, line);
        output.append(line + "\n");
    }

}
else
    cerr << "Unable to load Shader" << endl;

return output;

}
void Shader::checkShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const std::string& errorMessage)
{
GLint success = 0;
GLchar error[1024] = { 0 };

if (isProgram)
    glGetProgramiv(shader, flag, &success);
else
    glGetShaderiv(shader, flag, &success);

if (success == GL_FALSE)
{
    if (isProgram)
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(error), NULL, error);
    else
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, sizeof(error), NULL, error);

    std::cerr << errorMessage << ": '" << error << "'" << std::endl;
}
}

GLuint Shader::createShader(const string& text, unsigned int type)
{
GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);

if (shader == 0)
    std::cerr << "Error compiling shader type " << type << std::endl;

const GLchar* p[1];
p[0] = text.c_str();
GLint lengths[1];
lengths[0] = text.length();


glShaderSource(shader, 1, p, lengths);
glCompileShader(shader);

checkShaderError(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, false, "Error compiling shader!");

return shader;
}
```

---

Here is my Main.cpp

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Vertex vertices[] =
{
    Vertex(glm::vec3(-0.5,-0.5,0),glm::vec2(0.0, 0.0)),
    Vertex(glm::vec3(0, 0.5,0),glm::vec2(0.5, 1.0)),
    Vertex(glm::vec3(0.5, -0.5, 0),glm::vec2(1.0, 0.0))
};

Display display(800, 600, "Game Engine!");

Mesh mesh(vertices, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));
Shader shader("./res/basicShader");
Texture texture("./res/bricks.jpg");

Transform transform;

float counter = 0.0f;

while (!display.isClosed())
{
    display.Clear(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    transform.GetPos().x = sinf(counter);

    cout <<"Counter:" << counter << endl;
    cout << "m_pos.x: " << transform.GetPos().x << endl;

    shader.Bind();
    shader.Update(transform);
    texture.Bind(0);

    mesh.Draw();

    display.Update();
    counter += 0.1f;
}

return 0;
}
```

---

UPDATE: Here is my Vertex Shader

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec2 texCoord0;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
 gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
 texCoord0 = texCoord;

}
```

Comment: How is it possible that you don't even have *one* `#include` in your whole project? What compiler is this?

Comment: Did you check that the value returned from `glGetUniformLocation()` is valid?

Comment: Show your vertex shader.